# Java EE 6 SDK installation issue on mac 10.8

Tags: java, macos

I downloaded the file `java_ee_sdk-6u4-jdk7-linux-x64-ml.sh` for installation and even changed the permission by command `chmod +x java_ee_sdk-6u4-jdk7-linux-x64-ml.sh`, but I received the following error:

> This program requires DISPLAY environment variable to be set.
>   Please re-run after assigning an appropriate value to DISPLAY.

Comment: Typical for java. Makes troubles whenever possible.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try setting you display variable as follows

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Comment: Running this over ssh to Centos... Entering setup...
java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
 at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

You can also change to the C shell (csh) and set display=:0 and rerun the shell script.